# SVG file is not showing up in the mobile devices, but it is displayed under google chrome browser

Tags: svg

SVG file is not showing up in the mobile devices, but it is displayed under google chrome browser.

```
  <li>
    <svg class="listnew" xmlns="content/assest/airplane-mode-on.svg"    
    xlink="content/assest/airplane-mode-on.svg" width="100%" height="1000px"
    viewBox="0 0 219.5 66">
   <g>
   <img src="content/assest/fully-wi-fi-connected.svg"  width="40%"   
    height="100px;" />
    <p class="text-content">4 Active Apps</p>
   </g>

   </svg>

    </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of things wrong with your sample.

1. `<img>` is not a valid SVG element.  SVGs use the `<image>` element.
2. `<p>` is not a valid SVG element. It is HTML only.  If you want to put text in your SVG, you need to use the `<text>` element.
3. In `<image>` elements you reference the external file with the `xlink:href` attribute.  `src` is an HTML thing.
4. You have an invalid `height` attribute in your image. Remove the semicolon.

   ```
   <image xlink:href="content/assest/fully-wi-fi-connected.svg" width="40%" height="100px" />
   ```
5. Lastly your `xmlns` and `xlink` declarations in your `<svg>` tag are wrong.  You can't choose what to put for those. They are hardwired to a specific value.  Although it looks like a URL it is actually not. It is a string constant.  They **have** to be:

   ```
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   ```